# rails bootstrap missing classes

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I use rails 4 and bootstrap 3 and it has basic classes but many of them are missing. 
My gemfile

```
...    
    gem "therubyracer"

    gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS

    gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
...
```

my application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides 
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree
```

My application has only basic styles for forms and buttons but there is no many classes like **col-xs-6 col-md-4** so I can't build grid layout.

When I put example code from bootstrap site to my view

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

I've got this

```
.col-xs-12 .col-md-8
.col-xs-6 .col-md-4
.col-xs-6 .col-md-4
.col-xs-6 .col-md-4
.col-xs-6 .col-md-4
.col-xs-6
.col-xs-6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [Issues](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues) for twitter-bootstrap-rails, you'll see that a [frequently](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/690) [raised](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/695) [issue](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/663) is that the master branch is for Bootstrap 2.3.2, i.e. (the now-unsupported) Bootstrap 2 rather than Bootstrap 3. And that this isn't clearly mentioned in the README. Your example grid markup is from Bootstrap 3, so it won't work -- the grid system changed significantly between [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

To make this work, you'll either have to stick with Bootstrap 2 markup, or try your luck with the [Bootstrap 3 branch of twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3) instead.